# Макрос, отделяющий слипшийся текст с цифрами

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы

Пользуюсь Ворд 2003

Имеется вот такой текст:

> Golden165  has prepared several meso(phenylene oxides) of this type using a modification of Hunter's method. Сoworkers167 developed Hunter's work
> benzoyl peroxide169"171, lead tetraacetate or dioxide172, or copper(II) acylates173, in which trichloro-, tribromo-, tri-iodo-, and pentabromo-phenols gave meso(phenylene oxides) having molecular weights of2000-5000, melting points from165° to265°C, and cyclohexadienone terminal groups; potassium pentafluoro- phenoxide in the presence of copper(II) oxide yielded the corresponding polymer of molecular weight1700-4300.174
> The formation of meso(phenylene oxides) from m-halogenophenols has been investigated by Brown and his coworkers175"180. They find that the Ullmann poly- condensation of ra-bromophenol takes place at150-220°C to give the corresponding meso(phenylene oxide).

Текст большой :(

Как макросом цифры оторвать от слов.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
Sub NumbersSplit()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[A-zА-я][0-9]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute:
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Loop
End Sub
```